# Obtener un porcentaje con una única tabla

Tags: mysql

necesito hacer una consulta sql con una unica tabla y sacar el porcentaje y no me sale de ninguna manera es decir tengo una consulta de la cant total de obligaciones anuales x organismos que es la siguiente...

```
SELECT
    unicatabla.Organismo,
    COUNT( unicatabla.Obligacion ) AS 'Cantidad de anuales 2020' 
FROM
    unicatabla
WHERE
    unicatabla.Obligacion = 'anual 2020' 
GROUP BY
    unicatabla.Organismo
```

y esta otra que obtengo las anuales que estén cumplidas, yo quiero unirlas para que me de por organismo el porcentaje de cumplimiento, esta es la otra

```
SELECT
    unicatabla.Organismo,
    COUNT( unicatabla.Obligacion ) AS `Cantidad de anuales 2020 presentadas` 
FROM
    unicatabla
WHERE
    unicatabla.Obligacion = 'anual 2020' 
    AND unicatabla.Tipo = 'cumplidor' 
GROUP BY
    unicatabla.Organismo
```

ya probé con subconsultas pero no me sale, me ayudan??

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que veo diferente entre tus dos consultas es que en la de cumplidas agregas una condición adicional a tu where.

Entonces para juntarlas no será muy complicado, ya que puedes hacer en tu primer select un sum de los registros que tengan el tipo como cumplidor y sobre eso haces una división para obtener el porcentaje.

```sql
SUM(CASE unicatabla.Tipo WHEN 'cumplidor' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Dentro de el Sum hay un case que valida cuando el tipo sea cumplidor sumara 1, y en caso contrario no sumara, al final el agrupado te dará la suma de todos los que cumplieron la condición y a esa suma le aplicaras la división entre el contador.

```sql
SELECT
    unicatabla.Organismo,
    COUNT(1) AS 'Cantidad de anuales 2020',
    SUM(CASE unicatabla.Tipo WHEN 'cumplidor' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Cantidad de anuales 2020',
    SUM(CASE unicatabla.Tipo WHEN 'cumplidor' then 1 else 0 end) / COUNT(1) as Porcentaje
FROM
    unicatabla
WHERE
    unicatabla.Obligacion = 'anual 2020' 
GROUP BY
    unicatabla.Organismo
```

Comment: Gracias!!!! te agradezco mucho